# Super User not using my SE network profile

Tags: support, stackexchange, user-profiles, profile-page

Normally when I sign up on a different SE site it uses my existing SE profile... however that doesn't seem to the be case here.

Is there any way I can set it to my network profile without having to type everything manually?

Comment: Did you use the same log in method?

Comment: @Burgi I think so, but I wrote a post when I wasn't logged in (or signed up to Super User) and clicked 'submit'... and it wasn't giving me any kind of error message... then I logged in on a different tab and then submitted a question on here

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I set it to my network profile without having to type everything manually?

1. Go to [your SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049944/pealo86) (or any profile you want to propagate to SU)
2. Click "Edit Profile and Settings"
3. Scroll to the bottom and click "Save and Copy Changes to all Stack Exchange communities"

Comment: thanks, I've given that a go however I am still showing up as this 'user700248' unfortunately

Comment: Hmm. Then maybe the next step is to merge the accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: thanks, I've just tried that but the form tells me the accounts are already linked! very strange

Comment: Try getting a human involved. Use the same contact form and select "Other" for `What can we help you with?`. Fill in the other details as needed, and submit. Since automated processes don't handle `Other` very well, you should get an SE person to reply, or fix the problem.